# How to revert a Rails migration that has been checked in to git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rails-migrations

On my `development/feature` branch, I have a commit with `20150818113106_add_team_id_to_account.rb` (which adds a column to `Account`) & the `schema.rb` that results from applying the migration. This commit has been pushed, & also exists on `origin/development/feature`.

Now I want to revert this change- I do not want to add this column to `Account` after all. I can't work out if I should therefor revert the git commit, or run a `db:migrate:down` & commit the results of that, or both, or neither.

Comment: An important question: Is the migration already run on some other database than on your development machine?

Comment: No, so far this has only been run on my development machine, but it has been pushed to origin. I would like to know the "best practise" process to use if I was unsure whether this migration had been run anywhere else.

Comment: Sounds good.  I would assume it may have run so I would choose a solution that allows for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've run into a common problem here with rails:
The database state and the program code state are different things.

Try to separate the two concepts.

Normally with code you can just revert unneeded code.

Here however you need to update the database status as well.

If the migration up has already been run there are two options:

1. Use `rake db:down` to reverse the migration.  This can be a good option if the commit is the most recent one made and the migration to add the column was just run.
2. Use another migration to remove the column.  This can be the cleanest approach especially if the other migration is not the most recent.

If the migration had *not* been run on your database instance then you could just revert the code commit or in more complicated cases make a new commit to remove the code.

As to which to choose that may depend on whether the migration had been run anywhere else (other than your local environment).  If the migration has been run in CI for staging, or pulled for other developers who have run it, then you may wish to choose the 'leave code and add a reversing migration' rather than running the down locally and then trying to revert the code commit.  Once the migration has been run elsewhere you're probably better off with original migration, plus another migration (I was going to call this a down migration but that is incorrect, these will be two up migrations) to remove the column with no reverts.

Comment: OK, so my question then is: if I take open 1) and reverse the migration, my local DB is then in the correct state, but my migration is still checked in on the branch & would be run when I deployed (not desirable). Code-wise, is it better to check in the results of the rake db:down, or to revert the commit that adds the migration?

Comment: Great question!  I was actually mulling that myself.  I think the main difference may be whether the migration has been run _on other systems_ such as CI or pulled by other developers.  Let me update with that.

Comment: Since what I am really asking is "what is the best practise for reversing migrations in a distributed source control environment", I decided to go with option 2, write another migration to remove the column & check in those changes.

Comment: Yeah the simplicity of that is often preferred.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution (1)**

You can run the following to rollback the migration:

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=2015081811310
```

Then delete the migration from the repository as the following:

```
git rm 20150818113106_add_team_id_to_account.rb
```

Then Push these changes, and make these steps again if you deployed on server.

**Solution (2)**

Create another migration to remove this column as the following:

```
rails g migration remove_team_id_from_accounts team_id:integer
```

Then `rake db:migrate`, then commit & Push

Comment: Plus one (+1) for actual examples which my answer does not have :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just create another migration file with the below command which removes the column.

```
rails g migration remove_team_id_from_accounts team_id:integer
```

Later do `rake db:migrate` commit it and push to git.